# Dropdown - from a range - dynamic target using COLUMN() & ROW()

Tags: dynamic, range, dropdown, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create multiple dependent dropdowns. The image provides an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. There's a "Type", "Make" and "Model" column that will have multiple dropdowns (limited in image). The first dropdown targets a Name Range. The second dropdown is where I'm having trouble because I was hoping to target a Name Range dynamically:

=INDIRECT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN(),4)))

...so the next menu would see "Chromebook" was selected and target the 'Chromebook' name range and populate the dropdown with options. Can you dynamically target the value of the previous dropdown using a formula in the Dropdown (from a range)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0BSV.png)

I can get it working with basic targeting, but I was hoping to add dynamic targeting in the Dropdown (from a range)...just can't get it to retrieve the value of the first dropdown and use it's value to target a Name Range.